# facebook launch through LaunchUrl but can't come back to my app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                launchUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/{name}"),
                    mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
              });
            },
            child: Text("ok")),
```

- this is my code when i click on button it go ot facebook app in my phone but i can't come back to my  app why?
- i just expecting that i need widget or package to launch facebook and come to my app